# When to use . parameter and when to use [ ] to call a function in IOS

Tags: ios5

In iOS I have some confusion when calling a function.

```
-(void) function:(NSString*) str
{
   selectedstring = str;
}
```

When calling the function.

When should I call like:

```
self.function = @"My name";
```

and

```
[self function:@"My name"]
```

What is the difference between (.) parameter and [ ]

in iOS function calling?

Answer (score 0):

`myVar = self.property` is equivalent to `myVar = [self property]`

`self.property = anotherVar` is equivalent to `[self setProperty:anotherVar]`

Which you use is a matter of style.

Some people will tell you that the dot syntax should only be used for things that are actually defined as properties (with `@property`). I disagree with this. My opinion is that the dot syntax should be used whenever you're calling something that gets or sets a value, with minimal other side effects. Whether you have written the method yourself or synthesized a property to auto-generate it is not important: the important thing is whether it is related to getting and setting a value.

So `myArray.count` is fine, despite it not being a `@property` in the header file. But `myURLConnection.start` is not, since that doesn't return a value and is related to performing an action.

People do disagree with this. Some people don't like using dot syntax at all, since it could be confused with accessing the members of a struct (which also use `.`). Others are happy to use dot syntax for `@property`s, but not for other methods.